# Find array of objects in next array to replace

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I have two below arrays objects. I want to find all those IDs of first array, and make them active in second array of object, and the rest will have to become none at status properties.

```
var searchIDs = [{ "id":"6001", "other" : "..." }, 
{ "id":"6002", "other" : "..."}] 

var list = [ 
    {"id":"9666", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"9667", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9999", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9668", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9669", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6001", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6002", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6003", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6004", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6005", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6006", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6007",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6008",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6009",  "status":"none"}
]



for (var i = 0 ; i < searchIDs.length ; i ++) {

    list.find(v => v.id !== searchIDs[i].id).status = "none";
    list.find(v => v.id === searchIDs[i].id).status = "active";
    Array.prototype.push.apply(list); 


}



console.log('Final List : '  + JSON.stringify(list));
```

But when I try with find function with for loops, it doesn't work for now. How could I solve it? Appreciate for reading my questions! thanks!

Final result should be

```
[ 
    {"id":"9666", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9667", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9999", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9668", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9669", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6001", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6002", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6003", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6004", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6005", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6006", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6007",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6008",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6009",  "status":"none"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly. this might be what you are looking for

```js
var searchIDs = [
    { "id":"6001", "other" : "..." }, 
    { "id":"6002", "other" : "..."}
] 

var list = [ 
    {"id":"9666", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"9667", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9999", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9668", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9669", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6001", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6002", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6003", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6004", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6005", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6006", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6007",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6008",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6009",  "status":"none"}
]

// This line creates a new array with only the id's in it
const ids = searchIDs.map(line => line.id)


// We will map this array
// if the this line id appears in the ids list we can set the status to active. otherwise to none
var newList = list.map(line => {
  // you could also use .includes
  line.status = ids.indexOf(line.id) > -1 ? 'active' : 'none';
  return line;
})

console.log(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest searching for the items in the first list (searchIDs) in an [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call on the second list (list), we're essentially checking if each member of list is also a member of searchIDs.

This might not be super-efficient if searchIDs is very large, so one could create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check for membership using [Set.has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).

```js
var searchIDs = [{ "id":"6001", "other" : "..." }, 
{ "id":"6002", "other" : "..."}] 

var list = [ 
    {"id":"9666", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"9667", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9999", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9668", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9669", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6001", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6002", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6003", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6004", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6005", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6006", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6007",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6008",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6009",  "status":"none"}
]


list = list.map(r => { 
    return { id: r.id, status: searchIDs.find(s => s.id === r.id) ? "active": "none" };
})

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Ya, it works with map, the list may have other properties, so i have to pick the Kwarkjes's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
  var searchIDs = [
   { "id":"6001", "other" : "..." }, 
   { "id":"6002", "other" : "..."}
  ] 
  var list = [ 
    {"id":"9666", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"9667", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9999", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9668", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"9669", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6001", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6002", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6003", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6004", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6005", "status":"active"},
    {"id":"6006", "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6007",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6008",  "status":"none"},
    {"id":"6009",  "status":"none"}
  ]

  let resArr =  list.map(function(item){
     let obj = item;
     if(searchIDs.find(x => x.id == item.id)){
       obj.status = "active";
     }else{
       obj.status = "none";
     }
     return obj;
  });
  console.log(resArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting with a very basic approach as below, hope it helps you.

```
var searchIDs = [{ "id":"6001", "other" : "..." }, 
    { "id":"6002", "other" : "..."}] 
    
    var list = [ 
        {"id":"9666", "status":"active"},
        {"id":"9667", "status":"none"},
        {"id":"9999", "status":"none"},
        {"id":"9668", "status":"none"},
        {"id":"9669", "status":"active"},
        {"id":"6001", "status":"none"},
        {"id":"6002", "status":"none"},
        {"id":"6003", "status":"none"},
        {"id":"6004", "status":"none"},
        {"id":"6005", "status":"active"},
        {"id":"6006", "status":"none"},
        {"id":"6007",  "status":"none"},
        {"id":"6008",  "status":"none"},
        {"id":"6009",  "status":"none"}
    ]
    
    let newsearchIds = [];
    
    for (var i = 0 ; i < searchIDs.length ; i ++) {
        for(let key in searchIDs[i]){
            newsearchIds.push(searchIDs[i][key]);
        }
    }
    
    for (var i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i ++) {
        for (var j = 0 ; j < newsearchIds.length ; j ++) {
            if(list[i].id === newsearchIds[j]){
                list[i].status= "active";
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(list);
```